# Rails 4 Update Multiple Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Been at this the last 2 days and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to update multiple match_pick objects on a screen at the same time using `form_tag`. Bare `match_pick` records get created as soon as a user signs up. I then want the user to be able to update relevant info on these records and press a submit button. Here's what I have so far:

> **routes.rb**

```
post "match_picks/adjust_match_picks" => "match_picks#adjust_match_picks", :as => :adjust_match_picks
```

> **match_picks_controller.rb**

```
def adjust_match_picks
  puts "The update_match_picks method has been called"
  @match_picks_recd = params[:match_picks]
  puts @match_picks_recd.inspect    
  puts "The parameters are:"
  puts params.inspect
  puts "The object passed is:"
end
```

> **views/match_picks/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for adjust_match_picks_path, :method => :post do %>
  <% @match_picks.each do |pick| %> 
    <%= fields_for "match_picks[]", pick do |mp| %>
      <%= mp.text_field :id %>
      <%= mp.text_field :result_pick %>
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

The HTML generated by the above is as follows:-

```
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/match_picks" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="EIEFdhjkkfnkjfYjlkjdlkjCzxaxHeaXbkvu0wbLB1QsOj+o=" /></div>
```

The above code is giving the following error:

```
    ActionController::ParameterMissing in MatchPicksController#create

    param is missing or the value is empty: match_pick
```

It then highlights this paragraph

```
        def match_pick_params
          params.require(:match_pick).permit(:user_id, :match_id, :round_id, :result_pick, :team_id, :try_pick, :margin_id, :result_points, :try_points, :margin_points, :random, :closed)
        end
```

I've put some debug in each of the methods in the match_picks controller and the form submit seems to be triggering the `create` method of the controller instead of my custom `adjust_match_picks` method. It looks to me like the error is triggering because the create method is not being passed `match_pick_params`. But I don't want the `create` method triggering, I want my custom `adjust_match_picks` to trigger.

I haven't put any code in to handle what's being passed to the `adjust_match_picks` as yet because I can't even get it to trigger.

I'm hoping I'm doing something sill here as I'm at my wits end. Thanks for looking.

> **Edit 1**

The parameters that are getting passed when the submit button is pressed are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EIEFdhjkkfnkjfYjlkjdlkjCzxaxHeaXbkvu0wbLB1QsOj+o=", "match_picks"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>"1", "result_pick"=>"6"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"2", "result_pick"=>""}, "3"=>{"id"=>"3", "result_pick"=>""}, "4"=>{"id"=>"4", "result_pick"=>""}, "5"=>{"id"=>"5", "result_pick"=>""}, "6"=>{"id"=>"6", "result_pick"=>""}, "7"=>{"id"=>"7", "result_pick"=>""}, "8"=>{"id"=>"8", "result_pick"=>""}, "9"=>{"id"=>"9", "result_pick"=>""}, "10"=>{"id"=>"10", "result_pick"=>""}, "11"=>{"id"=>"11", "result_pick"=>""}, "12"=>{"id"=>"12", "result_pick"=>""}, "13"=>{"id"=>"13", "result_pick"=>""}, "14"=>{"id"=>"14", "result_pick"=>""}, "15"=>{"id"=>"15", "result_pick"=>""}, "16"=>{"id"=>"16", "result_pick"=>""}, "17"=>{"id"=>"17", "result_pick"=>""}, "18"=>{"id"=>"18", "result_pick"=>""}, "19"=>{"id"=>"19", "result_pick"=>""}, "20"=>{"id"=>"20", "result_pick"=>""}, "21"=>{"id"=>"21", "result_pick"=>""}, "22"=>{"id"=>"22", "result_pick"=>""}, "23"=>{"id"=>"23", "result_pick"=>""}, "24"=>{"id"=>"24", "result_pick"=>""}, "25"=>{"id"=>"25", "result_pick"=>""}, "26"=>{"id"=>"26", "result_pick"=>""}, "27"=>{"id"=>"27", "result_pick"=>""}, "28"=>{"id"=>"28", "result_pick"=>""}, "29"=>{"id"=>"29", "result_pick"=>""}, "30"=>{"id"=>"30", "result_pick"=>""}, "31"=>{"id"=>"31", "result_pick"=>""}, "32"=>{"id"=>"32", "result_pick"=>""}, "33"=>{"id"=>"33", "result_pick"=>""}, "34"=>{"id"=>"34", "result_pick"=>""}, "35"=>{"id"=>"35", "result_pick"=>""}, "36"=>{"id"=>"36", "result_pick"=>""}, "37"=>{"id"=>"37", "result_pick"=>""}, "38"=>{"id"=>"38", "result_pick"=>""}, "39"=>{"id"=>"39", "result_pick"=>""}, "40"=>{"id"=>"40", "result_pick"=>""}, "41"=>{"id"=>"41", "result_pick"=>""}, "42"=>{"id"=>"42", "result_pick"=>""}, "43"=>{"id"=>"43", "result_pick"=>""}, "44"=>{"id"=>"44", "result_pick"=>""}, "45"=>{"id"=>"45", "result_pick"=>""}, "46"=>{"id"=>"46", "result_pick"=>""}, "47"=>{"id"=>"47", "result_pick"=>""}, "48"=>{"id"=>"48", "result_pick"=>""}}, "button"=>""}
```

> **Edit 2 (SOLVED)**

I've realised I was using a `form_for` instead of a `form_tag`. WHen I change it to `form_tag` my custom route fires. Silly mistake!! Thanks for looking

Comment: Please post your parameters being passed to the controller.

Comment: Have updated the original post

Answer (score 1):

You should use form_tag instead of form_for because you are not using any model object in form here.

Answer (score 0):

Switch

```
params.require(:match_pick)
```

To

```
params.require(:match_picks)
```

Comment: I've done that and it's not throwing any error pages but now I'm getting `Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3,.....` . Also, why is the create action being called and not my custom `adjust_match_picks` action

Comment: Ok you're one step closer :). Typically index controller methods do not respond to post. So I'd ask you to run rake routes and post that to your question.

Comment: I've just realised I was using a `form_for` instead of a `form_tag`. Doh! Thanks for your help thedanotto. I'll update my original post

Comment: Any chance you know how I access the parameters in the object I'm passing. When I create an object from the parameters, each hash object looks like this when I 'puts mp.inspect` it to the console:- `["26", {"id"=>"26", "result_pick"=>""}]`.

Comment: @Al-d, did you get this last part working? I'm running into the same problem with unpermitted parameters and I can't seem to figure out how to access them in my controller update.

Comment: This was a while ago now but I did post what solved my issue above i.e. changed `form_for` to `form_tag`